# Chaitin's constant for lambda calculus and combinatory logic

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic, chaitin-constant

I have found some approximations of Chaitin's Constant for turing machines but I have not found approximations for others. I'd like to have a rough estimate or upper bound on it for lambda calculus and combinatory logic. I expect it to be very low as is the case with turing machines. For context I am exploring recursion in genetic programing and a major point I'd like to make is that most programs don't halt so there is a huge gain by only considering the programs which do halt. While I think most people would agree with this I'd like to have a more formal argument. Because I am using combinatory logic for my programs I'd prefer a Chaitin constant for combinatory logic. If the probability is very low it lends weight to my point. If it is somehow high I would be very surprised and rethink the idea.

Does anyone know of such approximations? If not for lambda calculus and/or combinatory logic what about for other models of computation which are not turing machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be relevant:

> We present a quantitative analysis of various (syntactic and behavioral)
>   properties of random λ-terms. Our main results show that asymptotically,
>   **almost all terms are strongly normalizing** and that any fixed closed term
>   almost never appears in a random term. Surprisingly, in combinatory logic
>   (the translation of the λ-calculus into combinators), the result is exactly
>   opposite. We show that almost all terms are not strongly normalizing.
>   This is due to the fact that any fixed combinator almost always appears
>   in a random combinator.

From [Asymptotically almost all λ-terms are strongly
normalizing](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5505).